# What can I engineer to power a normally simple project when a 7805 or LM2596 converter is not adequate?

Tags: power-supply

I'm trying to power a simple project, and normally for "higher" currents (ESP32,) and reducing a vehicle voltage  from 15 (12) volts down to 5 volts, we would use a converter (LM2596) module for example. The modules eliminate heat and work well, but in this project we are also using an ultrasonic ranging module. Even connecting just the input, no output of the converter to a separate power supply and bringing it close to the sensor changes the readings because both use frequency to do their job. The 7805 linear regulator from other posts here is not recommended for vehicles.[image]

Comment: you can buck to 7v, then 7805 for clean output.

Comment: Using a Buck  interferes with Ultrasonic Ranging Module. .. Just both being close to each other... We even tried powering each, buck and Ultrasonic module from different power sources. Its like RF interference ... It seams like A buck Converter and a Ultrasonic module can not be in the same vicinity or enclosure....??

Comment: Did you try a buck converter, that runs with a much higher frequency?

Comment: The uA7805 and its clones are old designs, and not usually automobile-temperature rated.      Specialized automotive linear regulators such as this <https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tps7a47-q1> might suit the need.

Comment: You might want to figure out what type of interference is the problem. If it's going through the wires, you can try filtering. Another option is magnetic interference, originating from the coil in the converter. This would make sense because you said: "bringing it close to the sensor changes the readings" If you know what type of interference is the problem, you know how to fix it. Do you have a picture of the way it's build? PCB design is important!

Comment: higher frequency I'll try that...  first,  as I hate power wasted as heat... But a liner reg, might be the only fix that I can see as can be seen in pic,,,WE have no room for a shield.

Comment: Thanks for response 
Bas Visscher
 Yes I'm pretty sure   its  magnetic interference as they both use frequency to do there work... But I don't have a foot of room to separate them... The esp32 has  no problem being powered by the buck.. just the sj-sr04 dam...

Comment: What if you use both in parallel, a linear regulator and the buck with a little higher target voltage. During the sensor activity you could disable the buck, or is this the main task?

Comment: Yes, The buck is being used as the power supply...  although no interference comes from wiring.. Its all radiated by EMI frequency.. Moving the sensor pcb  to the other side of the case has eliminated the problem. But means a lot  of CAD work ahead.. Moral of story... Watch distance between switching modules.... (Worked fine in breadboard stage..)    Thanks to every one who commented and helped..  and helping others is a good start for getting into Heaven...lol